# How i can upload files from javaFX app to server

Tags: java, spring, javafx, upload

I need you help, my lovely community! I searching samples of code where using upload files from java application to server.

My server works on Spring Boot, using REST controllers.

Now my programm can choose files, archiving them and it this archive i have to send  to my server

Comment: What type of server are you trying to upload to?

Comment: Please ask your question in detail of post not in title

Comment: I using Spring Server with REST

Comment: Since you're familiar with `Spring`, you can use `RestTemplate` to upload a file.  Perhaps https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-multipart-upload would lead you down the right path?